# Remove sort indicators Primefaces DataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a Primefaces DataTable with sortable columns. Even though it implements single sort (with and without `sortMode="single"`), the sort indicators on other columns do not disappear when I sort by a new column. It's purely for aesthetics, but I would like to remove the indicator once another column is sorted. I'm new to jsf and inherited this project, so there may be something happening behind the scenes that I don't understand. Here is a snippet from the xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable id="searchResults"
        value="#{searchController.searchResults}"
        var="emr"
        selection="#{searchController.selectedEmr}" 
        rowKey="#{emr.emrid}"
        selectionMode="single" widgetVar="theTable"
        scrollable="true" 
        resizableColumns="true"
        stickyHeader="true"
        rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
        sortBy="#{emr.emrid}"
        styleClass="stdSearchResult">                    
    <f:facet name="header">
        Search Results
    </f:facet>
    <p:column style="width:16px">
        <p:rowToggler />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Emr ID" sortBy="#{emr.emrid}" styleClass="wrap">
        <h:outputText value="#{emr.emrid}" title="emrId"/>
    </p:column>
```

Table:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code of the header column Model? I suspect you have mapped the sort column for Model column as sortBy="#{emr.emrid}"

Comment: Try to remove the custom styleClasses styleClass="stdSearchResult" and styleClass="wrap"

Comment: @Unknown, that is not the case. Each column is sorted by its respective data.

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar I will try that and let you know.

Comment: Sorry, that did not work either.

Comment: Do you have your own js? If so try to remove import... is logic happening in searchController.getSearchResults()? There should'nt be.. otherwise I would try to delete away until it works as it should be standard functionality

Comment: Sounds good, Jaqen. I'll let you know if I arrive at a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an obvious name now, but removing stickyHeader="true" accomplished the desired functionality. Thank you for the assistance.